# how can i change the values of arrays dynamically in each loop?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I have my data in an array so I am trying to change the values of arrays dynamically. For Example I have `$name[0]` inside foreach loop.

I want it to be `$name[1]`, `$name[2]`, `$name[3]` automatically in each loop. I am using laravel framework.

```
<tr>
 <td>Sn</td>
 <td>Name</td>
 <td>post</td>
 <td>Address</td>
 <td>father</td>
 <td>Grandfather</td>
 <td>Ctz no</td>
 <td>Contact</td>
</tr>
<?php $i = 1 ?>
@foreach($officials as $official)
<tr>
 <td>$i++</td>
 <td>{{$name[0]}}</td>
 <td>{{$post[0]}}</td>
 <td>{{$address[0]}}</td>
 <td>{{$father[0]}}</td>
 <td>{{$grandfather[0]}}</td>
 <td>{{$ctz[0]}}</td>
 <td>{{$contact[0]}}</td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: shows us you data array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could keep increment value of a variable while going through foreach

```
            <tr>
             <td>Sn</td>
             <td>Name</td>
             <td>post</td>
             <td>Address</td>
             <td>father</td>
             <td>Grandfather</td>
             <td>Ctz no</td>
             <td>Contact</td>
           </tr>
           @php 
            $i = 0;
           @endphp
           @foreach($officials as $official)
           <tr>
             <td>@php echo $i; @endphp</td>
             <td>@php echo $name[$i]; @endphp</td>
             <td>@php echo $post[$i]; @endphp</td>
             <td>@php echo $address[$i]; @endphp</td>
             <td>@php echo $father[$i]; @endphp</td>
             <td>@php echo $grandfather[$i]; @endphp</td>
             <td>@php echo $ctz[$i]; @endphp</td>
             <td>@php echo $contact[$i]; @endphp</td>
           </tr>
           @php
             $i++;
           @endphp
           @endforeach
```

this will work, but seems to be trivial, you could define a custom blade directive implementing your own rule in AppServiceProviders in Laravel. The official documentation is [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/blade#extending-blade).

Answer (score 0):

please try this

```
@foreach($officials as $official)
               <tr>
                 <td>$loop->iteration</td>
                 <td>{{$official['name']}}</td>
                 <td>{{$official['post']}}</td>
                 <td>{{$official['address']}}</td>
                 <td>{{$official['father']}}</td>
                 <td>{{$official['grandfather']}}</td>
                 <td>{{$official['ctz']}}</td>
                 <td>{{$official['contact']}}</td>
               </tr>
               @endforeach
```

Comment: only {{$official['name']}} is with officials table, others are from different table. They are generated from from controller. Is there any way to change the value of $address[0] to $address[1], $address[2] in every single loop?